How could I export a policy from one environment to another?
I am working with policy center v10 and gosu . I  would like to be able to export a policy on one environment and import it into another. What’s the best way to go about this programmatically  .
What’s out of the box options do I have to base my code around. What should I use to export it ?  Would this be easier on the sql side of things instead of policy center
How would I ensure a policy has valid dependencies when importing . What would I do if the policy account doesn’t exist on the import side .
Edits for clarity.
I want to make a tool in policy center that you click a button to export the policy to xml and import the policy with a different button. Remaking a policy is a pain and our production environments are too big to pulldown. It would be great if we could just pop into utilities and pull a certain policy then export it/import.
I have looked at the Guidewire documentation and I understand there is administrative data import export but I don’t think that’s what I want

Can you give a little more details on what you are trying to accomplish? If you are trying to run down an issue occurring in one environment and debug it in your local then it might be best to take a backup of the source env db and copy it to a db you can connect to with your local. Try to be more specific with what your issue is. The policy import/export is more tailored to being able to import a submission for Commercial prop/auto and may not work for all policy types.

I want to create an internal tool that would allow us to export a policy preferably into json and then import it . I understand that wouldn’t be hard with json views . I dont understand how I would parse it as an object.  And then import it . This would be beneficial for me because our prod environments are too big to pull down and it’s a pain recreating a specific policy.

This problem has generally been a difficult one to solve. The issue is that when you define an Integration View to export/import a policy, you then have to maintain it. I have seen some attempts to use the Archive xml created by anything in the Archive graph of the data model, which should in theory include all required data for a policy period (and be updated dynamically as the data model is updated). Any path you choose however is definitely significant effort and I am not sure the reward is worth that effort.

Sounds like you are looking for "Data Extractor for InsuranceSuite 9.0.4" Guidewire Accelerator.
Not aware of any function in base product could export and import individual account and policy from one environment to another environment.
However, there is an accelerator available on marketplace - "Data Extractor for InsuranceSuite 9.0.4".
It says:
"Full Extraction for all products - allows a single Account (BillingCenter, PolicyCenter) or Claim (ClaimCenter) and all related entities to be extracted from the database allowing this extracted set of data to be inserted into another database. This provides a means of export/import functionality typically used to isolate cases for debugging."
You may have a try, but please be aware that accelerator is out of support scope. It might need modifications to make it work with V10
Hope this helps.
Cheers!

For Policy Center v10 you have two options to transfer data into JSON or XML formats:

Integration Views
GX Model

GX Model is superseded by integration views, so I would consider working with Integration Views which actually supports JSON format.
You must define two components in order to create an integration view:

Define the Schema:
The JSON file that outlines the structure of the policy data you want to serialize. Place the schema under config/integration/schemas/com/yourcompanyname
Create the Mapping: The JSON file that maps the fields of the policy to satisfy the defined schema. Place this file under config/integrations/mappings/com/yourcompanyname

After defining the components, we need to generate wrapper classes that will handle the serialization process using the following command
gwb jsonSchemaCodegen. This tool will only generate wrappers for the schemas defined in config/integration/schemas/codegen-schemas.txt. The format is to indicate the name of one schema per line.
Finally, we use the wrapper classes we have created previously to generate the JSON. The code could look like this:
var mapper = JsonConfigAccess.getMapper("com.yourcompanyname.myPolicy-1.0", "MySchemaDefinedIntheSchemaFile")
var jsonString = mapper.transformObject(yourObject).toPrettyJsonString()

In order to implement your export feature, you can then create a PCF page with and Input Set where you introduce the policy number, retrieve the policy by querying the database, and then export it with by invoking the JSON mapper as shown above
For a detailed explanation, refer to the GW documentation following this route:
Integration > Data Transfer Structures > Guidewire InsurancePlatform Integration Views

That points me in the right direction but what would your ideas be about the import side. That seems to be the hardest part as there needs to be input validation if the account doesn’t exist or the policy already exists.
